# How can I compare two string variables?

Tags: php

I have these declared

```
$username = $this->users->getUsernameById($file->user);
$sessionuser = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

How would I go about comparing to the two values and if they match, execute code?
I had

```
if ( $username == $sessionuser){

blalghalhalhalhllahblahhblahhblahhh
}
```

However, even when the two variables are the same, it doesn't seem to trigger the `if` statement. Did I do something wrong? maybe not `==`, just `=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strcmp()` function - or `strcasecmp()` for case-insensitive comparison.

```
if ( strcmp($username, $sessionuser) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking PHP is very forgiving when it comes to comparison operations because of the loosely typed dynamic nature of the language.

Try this to debug your code:

```
echo $username . '<br/>' . $sessionuser;
```

You may find that the values you are expecting aren't actually the values you're getting.

Another thing that I frequently have to do when stepping through my code is to place something like this:

```
echo 'got here';
exit;
```

immediately inside the if block to very whether it is that the block is not executing or whether it is the code within the block that is not executing as I expected it to.